# simple Authentication and ACL using cornice

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, pyramid, cornice

I have a RESTful API written in pyramid/[cornice](https://cornice.readthedocs.org). It provides an API for an Ember client.

I have followed the [cornice tutorial](https://cornice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) and have a `valid_token` validator which I use on many views as methods of resource classes.

```
def valid_token(request):
    header = 'Authorization'
    token = request.headers.get(header)
    if token is None:
        request.errors.add('headers', header, "Missing token")
        request.errors.status = 401
        return
    session = DBSession.query(Session).get(token)
    if not session:
        request.errors.add('headers', header, "invalid token")
        request.errors.status = 401
    request.validated['session'] = session
```

Now I want to start selectively protecting resources. [The Pyramid way](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html) seems to be to register authentication/authorization policies. The `ACLAuthorizationPolicy` seems to provide access to the nice ACL tooling in pyramid. However, it seems that pyramid needs both authentication and authorization policies to function. Since I'm authenticating with my validator this is confusing me.

Can I use ACL to control authorization whilst authenticating using my cornice `valid_token` validator? Do I need to register pyramid authentication or authorization policies?

I'm a bit confused, having little experience of using ACL in pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an easy question :)

Shortly:

- What you implemented in your validator is already taken care of by Pyramid with an AuthenticationPolicy
- Start setting up a `SessionAuthenticationPolicy` with your custom callback ([see code](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/authentication.py#L1029-L1077))
- Once this `authn` setup, you will have those `401` responses, and your `session` value in the `request.authenticated_userid` attribute. You can also custom stuff in the `request.registry` object.

The only reason to keep your validator is if you want to return the `invalid token` messages in the `401` response. But for that, you can define a custom 401 pyramid view (using `@forbidden_view_config`)

Once you have that, you can setup a custom authorization for your views. You can find a very simple example in Cliquet first versions here : [authz code](https://github.com/mozilla-services/cliquet/blob/1.8.0/cliquet/authentication.py#L122-L133)  and [view perm](https://github.com/mozilla-services/cliquet/blob/1.8.0/cliquet/resource.py#L163)

Good luck!

Comment: So your advice is to avoid using cornice validators for authentication?

Comment: I am working on it. It seems I need to roll my own AuthenticationPolicy, the SessionAuthenticationPolicy doesn't seem suitable when authorisation happens on each request.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna do something like:

```
from pyramid.authentication import SessionAuthenticationPolicy
from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
from your_module import valid_token 

authn_policy = SessionAuthenticationPolicy(debug=True, callback=valid_token)
authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()

config = Configurator(authentication_policy=authn_policy,authorization_policy=authz_policy)
```

And ofcourse in the Configuration will receive other arguments like settigns, locale_negociator, ...........

Hope this will help